# Click event in d3.js

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event

I am trying to use the click event in a line chart in d3. Everytime I click on a line I want the line to change color to red and display the country name. The problem I am having is when click a line it changes color however it reverts back to the original color. The country name appears correctly.

This is the code to generate the line:

```
let line = d3.select("#linechart")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", widthline + marginline.left + marginline.right)
    .attr("height", heightline + marginline.top + marginline.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginline.left + "," + marginline.top + ")")
    .attr("id", "diagram");

line.selectAll(".line").data(databyCountry).enter()
.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", .5)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", d => lines(d[1]))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
.on("mouseover", countryOver)
.on("mouseout", countryOut)
.on("click", click);
```

this is the event code:

```
function countryOver(event, d){
    d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", 2);
   line.append("text")
        .text(d[0])
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .attr("x", x(d.date) )
        .attr("y", y(d.stringency_index))
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("id", "countryName");
        
    };

function countryOut(event, d) {
    d3.select(this).style("stroke", "steelblue").style("stroke-width", .5);
    d3.select("#countryName").remove();
    };

function click(event, d) {
    d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red").style("stroke-width", 2);
    line.append("text")
        .text(d[0])
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .attr("x", 500)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("id", "countryClick");
    };
```

Hope someone could help me! Thanks!